# DB table with an n:n helper table - read twice or duplicate rows?

Tags: database, algorithm, performance

This is a question about database access performance vs code simplicity and pest practices.

Let's say I have a `Users` table and an `Addresses` table. Every user can have more than one address, which will be stored in the `Addresses` table with a foreign key to the `Users` table.

What would be the best way to read users from the database, assuming that I always want to get the addresses along with the users?

**First option** would be to query the user, say by his username, and once I have the object, use the user's id to query the `Addresses` table for all the user's addresses.

**pros:**

1. Simple code
2. No duplicate data is transferred

**Cons:**

1. Requires two queries to the database

**Second option** would be to write a query that joins `Users` with `Addresses` and returns a user result line for every address the user has. All the columns, except for the `address` column, would be exactly the same for every line. I would then aggregate all the lines into a single `user` object with a list of addresses.

**Pros:**

1. Requires a single query to the database

**Cons**

1. Relatively complicated code (aggregating the users)
2. A lot of the data transferred is redundant

Those are the two ways I could think of, both have their pros and cons. Which of the options would you suggest?

Maybe another solution altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided to use

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT addresses.address SEPARATOR ' | ') addresses
...
GROUP BY userId
```

I then split the addresses into a list in the client (specifically, in my customer `BeanPropertyRowMapper`)

Answer (score 1):

My first rule of thumb is usually to let the database engine do what it is good at. Joining of tables is a basic function that the database performs with maximum efficiency. A join by the DB will always be faster than what you can do by making multiple calls.

The point you make about the fact that it fetches a lot of user data is true only if you have real problems with data transfer or the data is really massive.
In exchange, you are making just one call to the database instead of multiple calls. That saving can well outweigh the possible downside of data size.

I'm not quite sure what you meant by "aggregating the user data" since you just take it from the first entry of that user and skip the rest.

At the end of the day, let the database do its work unless there is a really good reason not to do so.

In really serious cases there are ways to bring nulls in the user data all but the first row. However, this complicates the SQL query greatly and, once again, is generally not worth the overhead.

Comment: Thanks. Would your answer change if the user were to have more than one n:n table causing a high order Cartesian product?

Comment: @summerbulb Once you start joining another table you have to be careful. Joining a number of tables only makes sense if there is some connection across them all. Otherwise you can get some really bad results. For exampple, if you have a customer table, a customer-addresses table (multiple addresses for one customer) and a customer-orders table then it makes no sense to make a 3-table join.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a long debate over it with Microsoft over [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1833#issuecomment-262324988) and a discussion with MS-SQL MVP.

Summarizing that thread (from my prescriptive):

1. To SQL Server it doesn't matter if you'll have a single query or 10, the redundant fields returned have 0 impact on SQL Server.
2. Splitting the queries is what SQL is doing internally anyway, and when people try to optimize SQL, it's usually to the worst as SQL is doing better when not forcing it do act in a specific way.
3. Having multiple queries have overhead on SQL.
4. The only thing that actually splitting queries solves is bandwidth on the network as there will be less bytes transferred over the wire, and he says it's negligible compared to having multiple queries.
5. When you have massive returned rows, you'll want to split the queries because of [Table Spools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181032(v=sql.105).aspx) and because of the bandwidth.